# How can I create a cuttable face with an odd number of vertices?

Tags: modeling, topology

As the title says.
[image]

On the right side there is an odd number of vertices. So I want to create a face with these vertices, but every time I try to do that, I get a non-cuttable face. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi there. Those verts should create a face when you hit `F`. How are you trying to create the face? Can you post the error you are getting please.

Comment: What's a "non-cuttable face"?

Comment: The face is an n-gon and therefore doesn't have directional edge flow

Comment: If by "cuttable" you mean to use the _Loop Cut_ tool on it, the simple answer is: you cannot create a cuttable face with an odd number of vertices. And actually it does not matter if the number is odd or even, if it's not 4, it is not cuttable via _Loop Cut_. You have to use something else like the _Knife_ tool for example.